# What can be placed in each Java for statement clause?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm teaching an advanced Java course in the fall. I know that the three, semi-colon separated clauses of a for statement can have multiple sub-statements, such as the following.

```
for(int x = 0, y = 0; x < 10 && y < 20; x+=1, y+=2) {
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

However, I cannot find a resource that details exactly what can be in each of the initialization, termination, and increment clauses, respectively.

[The official java documentation,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) doesn't give the details, nor do the numerous websites I've searched for.

I have deduced some of the rules over the years, but I would like to something more official than my deductions when I am teaching.

For example, the following two compile:

```
int x = 0;
for(System.out.println("initializer"); (x++)<10; System.out.println("increment " + x)) {}
```

and

```
int x = 0;
boolean cont = true;
for(System.out.println("initializer"); cont; System.out.println("increment " + x),cont=(x++)<10) {}
```

but the following does not:

```
for(int x=0,boolean cont=true; cont; System.out.println("increment " + x),cont=(x++)<10) {}
```

I have educated guesses as to why the first two compile and the latter does not, but I cannot give the definitive rules for each clause.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) is the official java documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is best answered by the grammar of the language.

```
ForControl:
    ForVarControl
    ForInit ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate]

ForVarControl:
    {VariableModifier} Type VariableDeclaratorId  ForVarControlRest

ForVarControlRest:
    ForVariableDeclaratorsRest ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate]
    : Expression

ForVariableDeclaratorsRest:
    [= VariableInitializer] { , VariableDeclarator }

ForInit: 
ForUpdate:
    StatementExpression { , StatementExpression }
```

Another source might be antlr, they have for example the Java 8 grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java8/Java8Parser.g4#L849

```
forStatement
    :   basicForStatement
    |   enhancedForStatement
    ;

forStatementNoShortIf
    :   basicForStatementNoShortIf
    |   enhancedForStatementNoShortIf
    ;

basicForStatement
    :   'for' '(' forInit? ';' expression? ';' forUpdate? ')' statement
    ;

basicForStatementNoShortIf
    :   'for' '(' forInit? ';' expression? ';' forUpdate? ')' statementNoShortIf
    ;

forInit
    :   statementExpressionList
    |   localVariableDeclaration
    ;

forUpdate
    :   statementExpressionList
    ;
```

Comment: Don't know where you got that first syntax, or why you'd want to show some antlr syntax, when the **Java Language Specification** has the *authoritative* language syntax. See [JLS 14.14. The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) *(as already provided in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476066/what-can-be-placed-in-each-java-for-statement-clause#comment110490071_62476066) to the question)*

Comment: Thank you @Stuck, that was what I was looking for.